# JavaScript Autosuggest/Autocomplete with some color text

Tags: javascript

I'm creating my own auto suggest with my input on HTML with pure JavaScript Standard DOM. I'm trying to code my own without using JavaScript Framework with external json file. This is my code so far:

```
<input type="text" class="input_data" id="Music_Genre" onKeyUp="suggestMusicGenre(this.value, event)" />
            <div id="musicgenre_suggest"></div>

function suggestMusicGenre(key, e) {

            var targetelem = document.getElementById('musicgenre_suggest');
            var temp_array = [];

            // basic style for div element
            $("#musicgenre_suggest").css({
                'position':'absolute',
                'background-color':'#fff',
                'width': $("#Music_Genre").css('width'),
                'cursor':'pointer',
                'border':'1px solid #a4a4a4'
            });

            $.getJSON('json/musicgenre.json', function(data) {
                $.each(data, function(index, value) {
                    var str = value.toString().toLowerCase();
                    var findstr = str.match(key.toString().toLowerCase());
                    var boolIfInsert = (findstr != null) ? temp_array.push(value) : false;
                });

                var prent = document.createElement('ul');
                    prent.style.listStyleType = "none";

                for(var o in temp_array) {
                    var chld = document.createElement('li');
                    var txtchld = document.createTextNode(temp_array[o]);
                        chld.appendChild(txtchld);
                        prent.appendChild(chld);
                }


                targetelem.innerHTML = '';
                targetelem.appendChild(prent);

            });

    }
```

and this is my json file content:

```
{
"AL"    :   "Alternative Music",
"BL"    :   "Blues",
"CM"    :   "Classical Music",
"CoM"   :   "Country Music",
"DM"    :   "Dance Music",
"EL"    :   "Easy Listening",
"EM"    :   "Electronic Music"
}
```

It works fine but I need to add more functionality in it like Facebook does which automatically making some suggested candidate string makes differ its color among to user already typed like example below:

[image: example image]

Is is possible with pure standard JavaScript? or should I use JavaScript Framework then?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery UI auto-complete for this. http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

### CSS

First, let's decide how out list item will look (this won't be the part of the final code, just to get the idea):

```
<div class="list_item_container">
    <div class="image"><img src="hanks.png"></div>
    <div class="label">Tom hanks</div>
    <div class="description">Actor</div>
</div>
```

And the formatting (this should go in your stylesheets):

```
DIV.list_item_container {
    height: 90px;
    padding: 5px;
}
DIV.image {
    width: 90px;
    height: 80px;
    float: left;
}
DIV.description {
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    color: gray;
}
```

### Javascript

Now, creating the autocomplete and overriding _renderItem() method:

```
$(function() {

    $("#my_ac").autocomplete({
        source: [
            {
                value: "Tom Hanks",
                label: "Tom Hanks",
                description: "Actor",
                image: "hanks.png"
            },
            {
                value: "Termionator 2",
                label: "Termionator 2",
                description: "Movie",
                image: "terminator.png"
            }
        ],
        minLength: 1
    }).data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        var inner_html = '<a><div class="list_item_container"><div class="image"><img src="' + item.image + '"></div><div class="label">' + item.label + '</div><div class="description">' + item.description + '</div></div></a>';
        return $( "<li></li>" )
            .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
            .append(inner_html)
            .appendTo( ul );
    };
});
```

Please note, that inner  is inside  tags. This might not be the proper HTML, but it's the only way to make the whole item clickable.

### HTML

Now just create an input with id `my_ac` and you are done:

```
<input type="text" id="my_ac" size="40" />
```

Reference [here](http://codeblogging.net/blogs/1/15/).